Jwt Token functionality but not being stateless
Im designing a spring boot + react webapp, now for authentication i wanted to go for Stateless authentication using JWT but i need features like user log out, remember me, idle time out, log out of all devices, see current logged in devices etc.
can these be implemented by JWT alone?
I saw people recommending few approaches including a mix hybrid approach like using short lived JWT access tokens, with refresh tokens which are stored in database with device Id and its IP address, and a table having list of blacklisted JWT tokens.
Also could use custom jti and storing it in database for revocation?
But this is not being completely stateless and would be difficult to scale.
I wanted to gain experience and learn more about JWts so using basic stateful sessions is my last option. Please let me know what would be the best practice to implement?
I wanted to use JWT stateless architecture but some features are difficult to implement

You'd need to revoke the token, see this question

for revocation would it better to:

use short lived jwt with refresh tokens and blacklist them or
use a custom jti claim and store it in db and blacklist that so it doesnt allow incoming jwt or
for logout just store jwt in a blacklist table with user Id

